# Initialise values in a Haskell list

Tags: haskell

absolute Haskell beginner here.  Not really sure what I am doing.

I want to create and initialise a list of pairs and later perform certain functions on them.  I am able to do this like so:

```
type Btype = (Char,Bool)

svar :: Char -> [Btype] -> Bool
svar x [] = False
svar x ((a,b):xs) = if (x == a) then b
                        else svar x xs

bt = [('a', True), ('b', True), ('c', False), ('d', True), ('e', False)]
```

This works and does what I want, just not the way I want it to.

To use this function I need to type:

```
svar 'a' bt
```

and I get True which is the value of the label 'a' so it works.

What I want, however, is to be able to somehow have the list bt initialised so that I can modify the function signature somehow

```
(svar :: Char -> [Btype] -> Bool)
```

so I don't have to type:

```
svar 'a' bt
```

but just type

```
svar 'a'
```

and get the same result.

I've played around with the data keyword and trying variations on the function with no luck.  It also doesn't help that I can't seem to shake my "programmers logic" out of my head and try to think in terms of functional programming.  So, having a bit of a rough time here.

Any tips/hints/solutions much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: How is the `svar` function supposed to know which list to look at?

Comment: Also notice that you are basically rewriting [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) which has a very similar signature.

Comment: Well obvious the function needs the list to work (remember haskell is pure) so the only whay you could do something like this is flee into some monad - either the State/Reader-Monad where you could hide your value in or go IO and do all the things you used to do in *other* langs :P

Comment: Well, thats what I want to know, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you ever need `svar` to use a list other than the one you've written in your question, `bt`?  If not, you can include `bt` in the definition of `svar` using a where clause or a let binding.

Comment: Specifically, you could implement Keshav Kini's suggestion like this: `svar2 x = svar x bt`, which would create a new function `svar2` which behaves as you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to use currying to incorporate the desired list `bt` into the function. For this, it would be more convenient to change the order of parameters:

```
svar :: [Btype] -> Char -> Bool
svar [] _ = False
svar ((a,b):xs) x = if (x == a) then b
                        else svar xs x
```

Then create a new function with currying:

```
svarbt = svar bt
```

Now the `bt` argument is built into the new function `svarbt`. This function is called with just one argument:

```
ghci> svarbt 'a'
True
```

Edit: This is just a more complicated way of doing what Neil Forrester suggests in his comment.

Comment: Cool, I went with what Neil Forrester suggested but yours was very helpful, I'm literally a few days into learning Haskell and anything is useful at this stage.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution involving library functions:

```
import Data.List

bt :: [(Char, Bool)]
bt = [('a', True), ('b', True), ('c', False), ('d', True), ('e', False)]

svar :: Char -> Bool
svar x = maybe False snd $ find ((==x) . fst) bt
```

`svar` is read as: `find the first pair` in which the `fst` is `==x`. This can produce `Nothing` is not found, or `Just somePair` is found. In the first case, return `False`, in the second case, take `snd somePair`.

A common idiom is also to use a helper function, e.g.: (as Keshav Kini suggests)

```
svar :: Char -> Bool
svar x = go bt
   where go :: [(Char, Bool)] -> Bool
         go []             = False
         go ((a,b) : rest) = if a == x then b else go rest
```

If efficiency is a concern, and you need to perform many lookups in a long list, you should transform it in a `Data.Map.Map` (a balanced binary search tree with O(log n) access).

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

btM :: M.Map Char Bool
btM = fromList bt

svar :: Char -> Bool
svar x = maybe False snd (lookup x btM)
```